# call jquery Animate scrollTop after class toggle in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, vue.js, jquery-animate

I am working on a FAQ page with vue.js

here is the example so far:

```
<li v-for="i in items | searchFor searchString"
 v-on:click="toggleCollapse(i)"
 :class="{ collapsed: i.collapse, expanded: !i.collapse }"
>
 <p><strong>{{i.q}}</strong></p>
 <p>{{i.a}}</p>
</li>


var vm = new Vue({
 el: 'body',
 data: {
  items:[
   {q:"test1", a:"a1", collapse:true},
   {q:"test2", a:"a2", collapse:true},
   {q:"test3", a:"a3", collapse:true},
   {q:"test4", a:"a4", collapse:true},
   {q:"test5", a:"a5", collapse:true},
   {q:"test6", a:"a6", collapse:true}
  ]
 },
 methods: {
  toggleCollapse: function(i) {
   var self = this;
   if(i.collapse){
    self.items.forEach(function(a) {
     a.collapse = true;
    });
    i.collapse = false;     
   }else{
    i.collapse = true;      
   }      
  }
 }
});
```

when user click on one of the items, the item will be expanded. The rest will be collapsed.

I want to call a jquery animation scrollTop function to scroll to the expanded item after users click.

I've tried vue instance such as watch, ready, mounted, updated etc but noe of them seems working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, nextTick willdo:

```
 methods: {
  toggleCollapse: function(i) {
   var self = this;
   if(i.collapse){
    self.items.forEach(function(a) {
     a.collapse = true;
    });
    i.collapse = false;     
   }else{
    i.collapse = true;      
   }
   this.$nextTick(function(){
     //command here
   })    
  }
 }
```